# Rotating “dippers” that throw oil into the pistons and cylinders

Tags: engine-theory

What are rotating dippers in "[rotating 'dippers' that throw oil into the pistons and cylinders](https://www.ultimatewasher.com/learning-center/how-to/pump-oil-change.htm#:%7E:text=Most%20pressure%20washer%20pumps%20use,into%20the%20pistons%20and%20cylinders.)"? Are they containers for taking up water, or maybe in this case, oil? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some engines, especially low HP single cylinder engines use a "splash lubrication" system instead of an oil pump.  This diagram:

[image: Splash Lubrication]

(Taken from: [Splash Lubrication](https://constructionmanuals.tpub.com/14264/css/Types-of-Lubricating-Systems-242.htm))

This type of system is used because it's cheap and simple and works well enough for this application.  As you can see, the "rod dipper" splashes oil from the sump all around the inside of the engine and enough gets into the moving parts to provide lubrication.

Some other types of engine-like machines use similar lubrication including piston pumps.  I believe that's what you're referring to in your question.

Comment: +1 for being spot on.

Comment: Yes, thank you so very much for your answer!